# Spring Security oauth2 cors filter isn't working

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

My spring configuration is deployed on Tomcat server.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                .allowedHeaders("Json-View","X-PINGOTHER","Content-Type","X-Requested-With","Accept","Origin",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method","Access-Control-Request-Headers","Authorization")
                .allowCredentials(false) //or true
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

For all requests for my api, the server returns 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, all works. But there is a problem with authorization requests to the address '/oauth/token', authorization is triggered, but the client can not read the answer for a reason "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource...". This is probably a configuration problem with Spring Framework.

```
GENERAL

Request URL: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

RESPONSE HEADERS

Cache-Control: no-store
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 10 Apr 2018 17:20:34 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

REQUEST HEADERS

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 85
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8081
Referer: http://localhost:8081/
Save-Data: on
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36

FORM DATA

username: user
password: qwe
grant_type: password
client_id: web
client_secret: web
```

Chrome console error:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/oauth/token: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What's wrong here? Why does Spring Security not return 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' for '/oauth/token' request? Spring version 5.0.4, the latest one at the moment.

Comment: Did you used spring boot?

Comment: No, I'm build war and a deploy it on Tomcat.

Comment: Then you may follow the link. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html
I think in `httpconfig` use `http.cors()......` should work.

Comment: It did not help. Works similarly, requests to the address '/oauth/token' not return 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header and on the other returns...

Comment: Then i would suggest add a filter which `imepelments OncePerRequestFilter`.

Comment: I would like to understand why the built-in mechanism Spring does not work. Don't working `http.cors()` and don't working `addCorsMappings(...)`. It seems to me that all this functionality is designed for Spring Boot, but it does not work with Tomcat in principle (((

Comment: I think built in method should works. Let me tell you about CORS. If `reload/load` a `page/url` from server, server added some http headers (if configured) and send it to the requester. so that the during the next request those exposed header automatically added. Additionally if you set some extra http headers and call it with ajax, then a preflight call happen first. since `/oauth/token` is post method so no extra header comes from server. you need to add it manually before call I guess. In my case, I always used filter for fine grained control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found for on url-address `/oauth/token` is to register a custom filter in the method `onStartup` overrided `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` Thus, it was possible to register the filter before the security filter.

```
override fun onStartup(servletContext: ServletContext) {
    super.onStartup(servletContext)
    val corsFilterReg = servletContext.addFilter("CORSFilter", CORSFilter.class)
    corsFilterReg.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*")
}
```

and CORSFilter

```
public class CORSFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

   protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
      if (path == "/oauth/token") {
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");
        if (req.getMethod().equal(HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name())) {
           res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
           chain.doFilter((ServletRequest)req, (ServletResponse)res);
        }
     } else {
        chain.doFilter((ServletRequest)req, (ServletResponse)res);
     }
   }
}
```

This example works as a supplement for `addCorsMappings` or a similar standard way of including the CORS in your application on Spring Framework `http.cors()` etc.